# Is there anything I can or should be doing about professionally embarrassing questions?

Tags: discussion

These days many prospective employers ask to see your Stack Overflow profile, or try to find it on their own.  The problem I have is that in the past I've asked questions such as [[this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382749/is-it-safe-to-mix-locks-and-interlock-operations).  Four years later just looking at it makes me cringe, and I've been tempted to delete it.  Some people apparently did find it useful though; since it does have some upvotes.

Still, if I applied for a positon that required expert level knowledge in writing multi-threaded code, and they ran into that quesiton without considering when it was written, my resume would probably find its way to the trash fairly quickly.

Has anyone else run into this issue before?  Is there anything I should be doing about it?

Comment: If your prospective employer has gone far enough to stalk your SO profile, than your resume is not in danger of being thrown away because of a few naive questions.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the question you asked, and it was three years ago.  You no doubt learned a lot since then.  It's not like it was downvoted into oblivion.  It was a reasonable question that was answered by the community.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Stack Overflow itself, but rather instead is about how potential employers would view a user's questions on Stack Overflow. As such, it is a better fit for [workplace.se].

Comment: The questions that an employer are most likely to see are those that have been upvoted the most (they're at the top of the list on your profile page by default)... as long as they are ok, you should be fine from casual stalking

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the question you posted either. However, I do have a colleague that for a while insisted online that UTF-8 or unicode for that matter does not have any support for umlauts and thus cannot be used for languages that use them, and several people clearly proving otherwise didn't seem to have any impact. If I were him, I might consider deleting that thread. Point being, if a discussion would be really really professionally embarrassing, I might consider deleting it.

Comment: It's worth to point out though that that was from another forum - for reasons already mentioned, usually through SO you generally get to see the best content a user has contributed anyway.

Comment: If I were a hiring manager, and I was putting time into scouring SO, I'd look at all activity over time and look for patterns. As many others have noted, it is unlikely you'd lost stock for asking a good, but more basic question. We all started from the beginning. When I read your question, I see a person who is able to articulate a question well enough to generate interest by at least 1,200 people. I personally answer ten questions (or more) to one ask, so I get where you are going- I always worry my questions are too basic.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should see some of the questions I've posted ;)

You post a question because you've hit a dead end with your code and can't see the way out. You've searched using Google, Bing or Duck, Duck Go and nothing's helping. You can't turn to your colleagues because it's 2 hours past the time when everyone else has gone home so there's only Stack Overflow left.

You post the question and leave for the night (after checking for any comments asking for clarification of your question).

You double check the question when you get home to make sure everything's still OK - no further comments, a few views and votes, phew you've not written a stinker.

You get to work the next morning and check your inbox. There's an answer. When you read it you realise that you've been an idiot and the solution was staring you in your face all along.

We've all been there. It's nothing to be ashamed of.

Looking at it from an employers point of view, I'd say it was better that you ask questions sooner rather than later - even if they are simple ones. The longer you struggle alone the more you're costing your employer. By asking you've actually saved them money. Though you don't want to be asking after 5 minutes of struggling on a problem.

Comment: *`Though you don't want to be asking after 5 minutes of struggling on a problem.`* - **Exactly...**, *that's it the point!*

Comment: _"You post the question and leave for the night."_ - I hate when that happens. Stick around for a minute or ten, you might get valuable comments on (the clarity of) your question.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't consider the question you've linked to professionally embarrassing. I've asked some pretty basic questions that seem so fundamental to me now - that's learning, and what SO is great for.

Also, consider that your question was from 4 years ago - in some ways it's good to see the progression of the questions you're asking (and answering).

There are some posts that I would consider professionally embarrassing. These are any where you've not bothered to ask a reasonably well formed question and any posts / comments that are adversarial or (quasi) abusive in nature. I'm not seeing any of that, so no worries there.

There's a slight difference if say, you were still asking very basic programming questions about a language and you were applying for a senior or lead role. But anything more than 2 years ago wouldn't factor in to my judgement of you from a recruitment perspective, unless there was a clear conflict compared to the work experience you're claiming.

Don't worry - as others have said, if you've got to the stage where they're checking out your SO profile. You're in a good place. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really really want to, [you *can* actually disassociate a post from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732), though this is not generally recommended unless you have a really good reason for it. You cannot do this yourself by pressing a button. Instead, flag the post in question, and write the moderator a short essay requesting disassociation and giving your reasons. The moderator will then pass it on to a Stack Exchange employee, who can make the post anonymous.