# What to do if I want to close my old and bad question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

For example, I have an old and bad question (my own), and I want to close it, but I can't. (I can only vote to close, and I did it long time ago) On the other hand, deleting it is probably not right, because it has 1 answer and somebody else may learn from it.

So, what do I do? I want to prevent users from accidentally writing another answer, because they will just waste time.

I thought about editing the title, but AFAIK this will bump the question, so it's more harm than good.

Comment: If you posted a link to your question, people who agree that it should be closed might close it. Of course, they may also upvote or downvote, which may not be to your advantage.

Comment: why do you want to close it?  Is it just bad (that isn't a close reason) or is it actually off-topic or otherwise close-worthy?

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's bad. In short, I'm asking about how to do a thing that really shouldn't be done. If this is not a close reason, then what to do?

Comment: As it has an answer, maybe you could rewrite it while keeping the answer correct. Another option is to [request for the question to be disassociated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261377/is-there-anything-i-can-or-should-be-doing-about-professionally-embarrassing-que/261424#261424).

Comment: The only thing that closing does is prevent SO users from posting answers to the question.  If it is truly crappy then there is very little "danger" of that happening :)  Just edit the question and note that you made a mistake.

Comment: If you're just embarrassed by it, you could flag it as **Other** and ask a moderator to disassociate it from your account.

Comment: Leave comments explaining your downvotes and over time your questions will be downvoted enough for you to delete them.

Answer (score 3):

- Case A: It needs to be closed by Stack Overflow standards and you want it to be closed but somehow it didn't accumulate enough close votes.

  Ask others for help. Not sure where would be the best place for that though. Commenting below the question on why it should be closed may be a start.
- Case B: You want it to be closed but it's on-topic.

  You may convince enough other close voters but if not, it will not get closed just because you want that. Other may still want to edit, improve or answer it. Others may want to make a shinning pearl from it.

  You may try to delete it though.
- Case C: You cannot close it but want to prevent others from writing answers and are comfortable with it being gone.

  Delete it if possible.
- Case D: You do not want to delete it.

  You may want to improve it making a good question out of a bad question.

Comment: Note that posting a request where one is involved (as is the case if it's the OP's own question) is strictly forbidden in SOCVR. It's allowed if the OP makes their question into a CW, but otherwise it's not. You should edit this answer to make that clear.

Comment: @cigien I have no idea about the rules of SOCVR. If that is a rule there I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's specifically [Rule 15](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-no-requests-youre-involved). It's quite a lengthy rule, but it's clear about the request not being allowed. As to *why* the rule exists, the FAQ hints at it, but if you want more details, feel free to hop into SOCVR chat, and ask. Members there will be happy to help clarify things. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

As the question has an answer (if it didn't you'd be able to delete it) you could accept that answer.

Not ideal - but it signifies to other users that the question is resolved so they are less likely to post an answer.